# Evince reader: How to make side panels dark in night mode?

Tags: gnome, pdf, evince

I love night mode in evince, but the reading always gets strained since there are white bars while reading the book. Is there any way to darnen them black? All black screen will be a pleasure for readers.

Please look at the image below, I wish to get rid of the side white bars. Enlarging the text is not an option because it reduces my reading speed.

Thanks a lot in advance!

[image]

Comment: If you change your system to a dark theme, then the outer parts should also turn dark.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps:

1. Install `lxappearance`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install lxappearance
   ```
2. Launch configurator:

   ```
   /usr/bin/lxappearance
   ```
3. And then in the *Widget* tab select *Adwaita-dark*.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug that Evince hasn't been respecting Dark Mode themes. It worked a few years ago, but not any more. See:

https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.bugs.dist/c/uXvCBWOVrcQ

https://issuehint.com/issue/elementary/evince/9

Newer versions [may have](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/1689) fixed this, but they've not come to you yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xrandr` with brightness `0.7` and gamma `1:1:0.1`.